# rails form_for select without property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

I'm trying to create a select list using the form_for helper:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@lesson) do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field('course_id', :value => @course.id) %>
   <%= f.select(:start_time, days_of_week_options_for_select) %>
   <%= f.text_field('starting_on', :value => Date.today.to_s(:short)) %>
   <%= f.text_field('ending_on', :value => "5 June") %>
<% end %>
```

(I'm using the bootstrap_form gem to make things pretty but that doesn't effect the issue, as subbing `form_for` for `bootstrap_form_for` doesn't change anything.)

It seems that the symbol `:start_time` above **has** to be a property of Lesson but I'd rather it not be as the field is only used *during* the creation of a new Lesson, but is not part of the Lesson model.

Specifically, this form serves to create multiple lessons and the actual date property on Lesson will be calculated depending on the value of the select dropdown.

Am I missing something in the bigger picture? Or do I need to learn some new syntax?

Comment: derp, what? do you want to use it but not persist in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way here is to use `attr_accessor` on your model. This will not persist to DB / storage but creates a temporary attribute you can use to store the info.

```
attr_accessor :start_time
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just avoid using form object helpers:

`<%= form_for(@lesson) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field('course_id', :value => @course.id) %>
  <%= select_tag(:start_time, days_of_week_options_for_select) %>
  <%= ... %>
<% end %>`

After you get the form to compile, you can look at the output of your ids and input names and name the select tag the same way, then it will work just like your other form elements.

See this for documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag

Comment: I actually had that working but it seems tricky to switch between bootstrap_form_for and bootstrap_form_tag with bootstrap_form. It's all about the bootstrap ;)